# How do I change the code font size in doxygen?

Tags: doxygen, font-size

How do I change the looks of how the source code is presented in doxygen? I mean, when you click the link to view the source code of the file(s) that generated the documentation. I'm interested in changing the font size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom CSS](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_html_extra_stylesheet) to style doxygen output.

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried that but I don't know how to do it specifically for the source code section. I tried something as follows in what I see is the only code related part of the css file:

    /* @group Code Colorization */
    
    span.keyword {
 color: #7F0055;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 11px;
    }

but that works only for the keywords and the other predefined code parts (keywordflow, comment, preprocessor, stringliteral, charliteral). Whatever in the code does not fall into those categories is not affected.

Comment: Looking at the Doxygen output, it uses a class named "fragment" for code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you'll need to use custom CSS, which you can do through `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET`.

To get a CSS template, run:

```
doxygen -w html header.html footer.html customdoxygen.css
```

You can then choose out elements from `customdoxygen.css` that you wish to modify, and add them to your own css file.

The CSS which ultimately informs the font-size of code snippets (`fragments`), is actually the `div.line` within:

```
div.line {
    font-family: Consolas, "Liberation Mono", Menlo, Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    ...
}
```